# Firestore REST authentication

Tags: c#, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firestore with c#, but the only libraries that allow that are in prerelease and require authentication through an environment variable. So after reading the docs I started looking at the REST API. My issue is that because of the application I cant set the rules to open, I need some form of authentificaion. I was wondering if I could do something like this

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA?auth=MY_AUTH_KEY
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for the Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token) describes what you need to do to authenticate with a Firebase Auth token:

> After you obtain either a Firebase ID token or a Google Identity OAuth
>   2.0 token, pass it to the Cloud Firestore endpoints as an `Authorization` header set to `Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}`.

Comment: Where do i get the firebase ID token? is it the database secret?

Comment: No, you get it from Firebase Authentication.

Comment: So how do I get it? (This is my second time using firebase/firestore)

Comment: In your environment, I don't know.  You might want to formulate a new question to describe the new problem and what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help

Comment: May I know how do you get {YOUR_TOKEN} from the JSON token file generated from service account?

Comment: did you get any solution @AndrewSee